# Getting syntax error upon passing the member function to template function

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

To start with, I use C++ 17 standard.

The code I am having issues with works fine unless I attempt to use it in a class with the same template function.

The following line of code:

```
    auto t = make_tuple_seq(std::make_index_sequence<numArgs>{}, &lzuint<T, A...>::helper);
```

causes like 10 compilation errors along the lines of "t could not be initialized" which I frankly cannot see reason for.

My previous attempt has been with the lambda function instead of helper member function which resulted in unreadable errors too.

Here I provide the minimum code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
template<typename _func, size_t... I>
auto make_tuple_seq(std::index_sequence<I...>, _func&& func)
{
    return std::make_tuple(func(I)...);
}
constexpr const auto numArgs = 2;
template<typename T, typename... A>
class lzuint
{
protected:
    size_t helper(size_t i)
    {
        return this->body.size() - numArgs + i;
    }
public:
    lzuint(const std::function<T(A...)>& func, A... args) : f(func), body({ args... }) {}

    const uint32_t& operator[](size_t index)
    {
        auto t = make_tuple_seq(std::make_index_sequence<numArgs>{}, &lzuint<T, A...>::helper);
        while (body.size() - 1 < index)
            body.push_back(std::apply(f, std::move(t)));
        return body[index];
    }
private:
    std::vector<T> body;
    std::function<T(A...)> f;
};
using ullong = unsigned long long;
int main()
{
    auto tup = make_tuple_seq(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, [&v](size_t i) {return v[i]; });//Note:this one works just fine
    lzuint<uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t> lzu([](uint32_t i, uint32_t j) { return i + j; }, 1, 1);
    lzu[1];
    lzu[10];
    lzu[11];
    lzu[12];
    lzu[13];
    return 0;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated as I am currently trying to get my head around the variadic templates by creating smth like simulation of the "lazy evaluation" technique.

The first error I get is

```
source.cpp(19): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

Comment: The "minimum code" is incomplete. What is, for example, `_func`?

Comment: Please post the actual error messages and actual code.

Comment: I am sorry for that mistake, I have edited the question to include both actual code and first error I receive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lzuint<T, A...>::helper` is a non-static member function. It needs an object to be called on. The object (which becomes the `this` pointer inside the function) is commonly passed as a hidden first argument, hence the message that function doesn't take one argument.

There are two ways to solve this: Either use lambdas

```
auto t = make_tuple_seq(std::make_index_sequence<numArgs>{},
                        [this](size_t i) { return helper(i); });
```

Or use `std::bind`:

```
auto t = make_tuple_seq(std::make_index_sequence<numArgs>{},
                        std::bind(&lzuint<T, A...>::helper, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

Using lambdas is usually the recommended solution.

Comment: The sample you have provided works really well, thank you for that.

I suppose I should always get enough sleep prior to posting questions here as it now seems pretty obvious to me. Thanks a ton!